# How can I sign up for the "Steam for Linux" beta?

Tags: steam

[Steam for Linux is in limited beta!](http://steamcommunity.com/games/221410/announcements/detail/1783684045487052635)

I looked around on the Steam Community web site, but I can't find anything that seems to indicate that I can take part in the beta.

Usually, Steam provides some sort of sign-up space where you can request to be a part of the various betas that they are running.  In this case, I can't find anything like that.

**Can I sign up to be a part of the Steam for Linux beta?  If so, how?**

Comment: I think you had to sign up a while back, and then they picked some of those who had signed up to be in the limited beta.  I don't think you can sign up at the moment, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Fill in the survey.](http://www.valvesoftware.com/linuxsurvey.php)
2. *If* and *when* you get selected in the future, you'll get an email welcoming you to the beta.
3. *(optional)* Fall to despair and install Steam for Linux anyway with one of the known workarounds.

Comment: Since 3. potentially gets you in ToS trouble, I'm not going to Google it for you ;)

Comment: I'm not interested in playing chicken with the ToS - I'll stick with #1 and #2. Thanks.